# Unknown error for Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image (Android Studio)

Tags: android, sdk

When I go into the SDK manager in Android Studio, and I go to the tab that says SDK Update Sites, It says "unknown error" next to Google Inc. (x86 System Image). I can never update Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image and I think its holding me back on some features to some apps. How can I fix this?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you get any solution?

Comment: Hey did you try the answer below. Just because it didn't work for me, doesn't mean it won't work for you. Also, One day, I believe, it just started working for, me, so make sure you have the newest version of android studio and if necessary, re-install android studio, This should work for you: [link to website](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/uninstallreinstall-android-studio). Hope this helps!

Comment: I ususally don't reboot my system. I rebooted my system and it seems to work fine.

Comment: make sure your android emulator is turned off during update.

Answer (score 26):

Just go to File -> Invalidate Cache/restart -> Invalidate Restart. Once done, Android Studio will close and restart. Allow all the updates to be installed and along, Intel Atom x86 system image will also be installed.

Comment: Worked for me after a _Failed packages:
- Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image (system-images;android-24;google_apis;x86)_ message.

Comment: I got the error "An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image: Read timed out." Did the cache/restart and installed it again... success! :-D

Comment: I was getting this error "missing system image for google apis x86_64" when trying to add emulator.. The above step "Invalidate Restart" helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

---

If none of the suggested solutions works for you, try to **run Android Studio as Administrator**.

---

Also **ensure there's enough disk space** on the partition which you installed Android Studio on.

It takes approx. 4Gb even though it says ~930mb. Keep that in mind!

To ensure diskspace is not the problem go to:

`File`→`Settings`→`Appearance & Behaviour`→`System Settings`→`Android SDK`→`SDK Platforms`

then check `[X] Show Package Details` and scroll to the Android package you want to install (e g. "Android 7.1.1 (Nougat)").
Check `[X] Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image` and hit `Apply`. Warning will appear in case of insufficient disk space.

Answer (score 3):

Delete the folder .downloadIntermediates from your SDK location. It works for me

Comment: Did not worked for me

Answer (score 1):

## I had same problem with android studio and performing below steps solved the problem.

Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Updates > Canary Channel > Check Now > Stable Channel > Check Now > Android SDK > Show Package Details > Apply

## No Error

## Download and Install Update

Comment: While this context may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

I felt super stupid. I landed on this page after googling the error. I tried the Invalidate Cache thing. didn't work. Looked deeper into the error and tried doing as it said, manually removing the system image it was trying to overwrite. I couldnt. It was in use. wtf. oh, the emulator i had going slipped past me, it didn't shutdown with the android studio restart and updating.

Closed the emulator and the upgrade finished successfully instantly.

Check for instances of the system image file running, the file from folder C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86

Comment: Haha same issue here, thanks. We are on the same "stupidity" boat now.

Answer (score -1):

You need to reinstall it.

1. Run "SDK Manager" in stand-alone mode,
   you should see the item marked as broken at the bottom, In "Extras" folder.
2. Delete the package, "Broken Intel x86...//"
3. Run the app again. It will be reinstalled.

Comment: When It reinstalled, it said it was still broken

Comment: Same issue @ConnorT