# ionic cordova run android An error occured while running subprocess native-run

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to run my ionic app on an android device (Xiaomi Pocophone) by running the following command:

ionic cordova run android

However, I get the following error message:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 7s
42 actionable tasks: 42 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):
        C:\laragon\www\ionicProject\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk

> native-run.cmd android --app 

platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk --device

[native-run] Selected hardware device 4d65535f

[native-run] Installing platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk...

[native-run] ERR_UNKNOWN: Non-zero exit code from adb: 1

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess native-run.

native-run.cmd android --app 
platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-d... exited with exit code 1.


Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

My phone are properly connected via usb type c cable, developer mode is already turned on and usb debugging mode is turn on

i have tried restarting PC and turn off unrelated IDE such as Laragon

Below are Java JDK 8 installed on my computer, i am using Windows 10 Pro

[image: java jdk 8]

The Environment Variable system path are as below

[image: 1]

Comment: update 3/9/2019, tried running 
``` ionic cordova run android --list ``` 
and the result came out as below

Comment: Errors (!):
ERR_UNSUITABLE_API_INSTALLATION: No suitable API installation found

Connected Devices:
Xiaomi POCOPHONE F1 (API 28) 4d65535f

Virtual Devices:
No virtual devices found

Comment: tried running command ```native-run android --sdk-info ```

Comment: Missing Packages: Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image  system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86  /.+/

Comment: currently trying the solution suggested here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369775/unknown-error-for-google-apis-intel-x86-atom-system-image-android-studio

Comment: Problem solved! using above solution

Comment: Which answer  solved your problem ?  I checked it, it seems related to Android Studio instead of ionic ? Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. I allowed "Install via USB" in the developer options in my phone which results success

Comment: this works for me. im using redmi note 8 pro

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late but it might help people in the future.
This error is most probably cause by no storage / memory full in phone you are trying to build your apk on.
So make some space and try building again.

[Check this git issue for the details](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/18995)

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable both Install via USB and USB debugging in Developer options:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a general solution for this problem, but I solved this cleaning up my phone's storage/memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try :
`ionic cordova platform rm android` 
`ionic cordova platform add android` 
and `ionic cordova run android --device`

It's work for me !

Answer (score 0):

I run the command with --verbose and realized its either a problem with not enough storage on the phone or a restriction from the device itself
so if you don't have enough space on the phone make sure to make a space on your storage

Answer (score 0):

use --verbose parameter in ionic cordova run and get the correct error message, which can range from unauthorized usb use to not enough space on device.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure these 2 options are activated in the developer options.

- `USB debugging`
- `Install via USB`

For Xiaomi devices, you have only `8 seconds to confirm` the installation on your phone. after 8 seconds the installation will be denied automatically and you have to try again.